# Swift (iOS) TokenAuthenticationStrategy gives me an unresolved identifier error for AlchemyLanguage API

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-watson, alchemy, alchemyapi

I get an error `unresolved identifier` when I try to follow the steps to use AlchemyLanguage iOS API with Swift. I have imported WatsonDeveloperCloud and have the following two lines:

```
let token = TokenAuthenticationStrategy(token: "myApiKeyGoesHere")
let alchemyLanguageInstance = AlchemyLanguage(tokenAuthenticationStrategy: token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to instantiate an `AlchemyLanguage` object in the most recent version of the Watson Developer Cloud iOS SDK:

```
let alchemyLanguage = AlchemyLanguage(apiKey: "<api-key>")
```

Unfortunately, the readme was not updated to reflect a change in December that renamed the `TokenAuthenticationStrategy` class to `APIKeyAuthenticationStrategy` and the `AlchemyLanguage(tokenAuthenticationStrategy:)` init method to `AlchemyLanguage(authStrategy:)`. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/issues/209) to track this problem on the Watson Developer Cloud iOS SDK repository.